# innerHTML change text

Tags: javascript, document, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm having some difficulty here with the document.getElementById() settings with javascript.

```
<div id="display">
        <p></span></p>
        <p>Inputs:<br /><span style="font-size:20pt"></p>
        <a id="btn0">&bull; Input 1</a><br>
        <a id="btn1">&bull; Input 2</a><br>
        <a id="btn2">&bull; Input 3</a><br>
        <a id="btn3">&bull; Input 4</a><br>
        <a id="btn4">&bull; Input 5</a><br>
        <a id="btn5">&bull; Input 6</a><br>
        <a id="btn6">&bull; Input 7</a><br>
        <a id="btn7">&bull; Input 8</a><br>
        <a id="btn8">&bull; Input 9</a><br>
        <a id="btn9">&bull; Input 10</a><br>
        <a id="btn10">&bull; Input 11</a><br>
        <a id="btn11">&bull; Input 12</a><br>
        <a id="btn12">&bull; Input 13</a><br>
        <a id="btn13">&bull; Input 14</a><br>
        <a id="btn14">&bull; Input 15</a><br>
        <a id="btn15">&bull; Input 16</a><br>
        </span> </p> </div>
```

and this is my script that is changing these items:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Parses the xmlResponse from status.xml and updates the status box
function updateStatus(xmlData) {
    // Check if a timeout occurred
    if(!xmlData)
    {
        document.getElementById('display').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'inline';
        return;
    }

    // Make sure we're displaying the status display
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = 'inline';

    // Loop over all the LEDs
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'input'+i) == '1')
            document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#d00';
            document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = '&bull; WARNING';
        else
            document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#090';
    }

    // Loop over all the buttons

    // Update the POT value
    document.getElementById('analogue0').innerHTML =getXMLValue(xmlData,'analogue0');
    val=0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    val=val+10;
    if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'analogue0') >val)
        document.getElementById('pot' + i).style.color = '#090';
    else
        document.getElementById('pot' + i).style.color = '#fff';
    }

    // Update the POT value 2
    document.getElementById('analogue1').innerHTML =getXMLValue(xmlData,'analogue1');
    val=0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    val=val+10;
    if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'analogue1') >val)
        document.getElementById('1pot' + i).style.color = '#090';
    else
        document.getElementById('1pot' + i).style.color = '#fff';
    }


}
setTimeout("newAJAXCommand('status.xml', updateStatus, true)",500);
</script>
```

I'm having the problem when trying to change the text between the a tags.
The color of the text changes fine, but when it comes to changing the text nothing is happening. I've read into this but cant find anything that looks like this on google.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Is there a Javascript error being thrown?

Comment: Did `getXMLValue` returns desired data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one statement that you want to be executed when an `if` condition returns true, you need to surround them in curly brackets.

Change

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'input'+i) == '1')
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#d00';
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = '&bull; WARNING';
    else
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#090';
}
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'input'+i) == '1') {
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#d00';
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = '&bull; WARNING';
    }
    else
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#090';
}
```